# Githib is putting my branched commits in to my master branch. Is this expected behavior?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I've done some experimenting with git branching and one particular set of commands drastically changed the way my graphs looks like.

The git in question is here:
[Link to Github](https://github.com/cveto/testingbranch5)

**What was being tested:**

*Look only at the right part of the graph, last 5 commits or so.*

- One branch (branch1) diverged from master.
- There were 3 changes on the branch1 afterwards.
- There was 1 change on master afterwards
- Merge was performed on branch1 with master to "keep up to date with master". *So far the graph looked as what expected*
- Merge was performed on masters developement on that branch is finished. *This is where the 2 graphs change drastically. I wanted what I have drawn with mspaint, but I got the image below.*

**What I expected**
To see a nice graph like on the sketch above the picture

**What I got**
Complete rewrite of the history - commits which were done in the branch now appear in the master.

**Questions**
Is this expected behavior? A rewrite of history was made with merge and all my branch1 commits are now visible in the master which I do not want to happen?

Can I somehow undo this and go to previous stage, to se the nice graphs I have had?

[image: Graph changes after merge]

**EDIT1**
I am starting to think this might just be a github representation bug. I am seeing branch commits on my master branch, which shouldn't be the case - unless someone tells me it is

Comment: You can undo you commits on master using `git reset --hard commit` replace commit with hash of the commit you want to restore to (before merge).

Comment: I tried that, and it puts me to the previous commit - however it is climbing back on the new tree. i.e. I can still see the history of my "branch" commits in my "master branch" that were added after merge. I assumed merge does not change the history, which is why I want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Merge was using fast-forward**

I am using the follwoing code instead:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

I looked at the documentation on: [Attlasian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing) and saw that git merge will use FastForward by default if it can. Allthough not visible from the simple example on the Attlasian, FastForward will change the history in a way that it won't be clear anymore which commit was done in which branch.

This is a behavour I do not want. In my master branch I want to only keep commits that were actually done in the master branch, not have them mixed up with a certain branch.